RNN Training Issue: Loss Not Decreasing with batch_first=False
I'm currently working on training an RNN model using PyTorch, and I've encountered a persistent issue where the loss does not decrease when batch_first=False. Despite thorough debugging, the problem persists. Here are the specifics of my setup and the problem:
Code Snippets:
# Imports and Setup:

print("Program starts")
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define hyperparameters
input_size = 500
batch_size = 20
sequence_length = 3
epochs = 20
num_layers = 2
num_classes = 1053
hidden_size = 256
learning_rate = 0.001

# Set device
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Load dataset (replace with your actual file paths)
X = np.array(pd.read_csv(r'D:\Ashwin\Desktop\Nlp course\Rnn_my_own\wizard_X.csv'))
Y = np.array(pd.read_csv(r'D:\Ashwin\Desktop\Nlp course\Rnn_my_own\wizard_Ys.csv'))

# Trim dataset for testing
X = X[:200]
Y = Y[:200]

# Dataset Preparation:

class Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        super(Data, self).__init__()
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample = self.X[idx], self.Y[idx]
        return sample

# Create dataset and dataloader
dataset = Data(X, Y)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


# Model
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_layers, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(1053, 500)
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device=device)
        embed = self.embed(x)
        out, _ = self.rnn(embed, h0)
        out = self.fc1(out[:, -1, :])
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out

# Initialize model and move to device
model = RNN(input_size, num_layers, hidden_size, num_classes).to(device=device)



# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Training loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for data, targets in dataloader:
        data = data.to(device=device, dtype=torch.long)
        targets = torch.argmax(targets, axis=1).to(device=device)

        # Forward pass
        scores = model(data)

        # Calculate loss
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)
        print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{epochs}], Loss: {loss.item()}")

        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

Issue Details:
Problem Description: When batch_first=True, the model trains correctly with decreasing loss. However, when batch_first=False, despite ensuring all shapes are correctly handled (hx initialization, data reshaping), the loss remains consistently high and does not decrease over epochs.
Debugging Attempts: I've verified:
Correct initialization and handling of hx and initial hidden states.
Consistent reshaping and processing of input data (X) and targets (Y).
Optimizer configuration (Adam) and learning rate (0.001) seem appropriate.
Used debug prints to monitor shapes and values through the training loop, confirming data flow and processing.
I'm seeking advice on potential causes or overlooked aspects that could be contributing to the loss not decreasing with batch_first=False in my RNN training setup. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
